# How do you load repo when testing web componets in phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I created a very simple project with postgres db as backend. Both my web code and api code works perfectly. Now I am trying out the testing aspect of Phoenix and I am running into problem.
When I run the test, I get the following error

> ** (Mix) Could not load FooWeb.Repo, error: :nofile. Please configure your app accordingly or pass a repo with the -r option.

I see repo defined in foo/config/config.exs folder and there is no repo definition in foo_web/config folder. Since the application is working properly, how do we enable testing to use the Repo defined in the foo/config folder?

Comment: Can you post your `config/test.exs` file?

Comment: What tutorial are you following?  Assuming you named your project Foo, the repo name should be `Foo.Repo`, so the question is how you ended up with a repo named `FooWeb.Repo`.  Did you start your project, then decide to rename it by manually changing the module names?  Not gonna work...because there are lots of files that use the original name of the project.

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Assuming you created your project with the command `$ mix phx.new foo`, the repo name should be Foo.Repo, so the question is how you ended up with the name FooWeb.Repo in one of your files. Did you start your project, then decide to rename it by manually changing the module names? There are lots of files that use the original name of the project. *There is no repo definition in foo_web/config* -- mix does not create a `foo_web/config` directory in my projects only the file `config/config.exs`.  The only thing I need to do to run tests is `$ mix test`.

Comment: The module that defines the repo should be in `lib/foo/repo.ex`. Your test config (`config/test.exs`) should contain a.  configuration for that repo (`config :foo, Foo.Repo, adapter: ...`). Your test helper (`test/test_helper.exs`) contains code that starts the Repo manually, in sandbox mode.